# I'm unable to run ng serve command in the terminal

Tags: node.js, angular

PS C:\Users\naveen.chennagalla.vscode\AsPage6> ng serve
Node.js version v10.15.3 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v12.20, v14.15, or v16.10.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

PS C:\Users\naveen.chennagalla.vscode\AsPage6>

Comment: Please update node to v14x from here https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.0/

Answer (score 1):

Compatibility list for Angular/Angular-CLI and Node.js might help you.
[image: Compatibility list for Angular/Angular-CLI and Node.js]